# 1.0e-03 * 0.9734 numerical representation in Matlab

Tags: matlab

Is 1.0e-03 * 0.9734 equivalent to 0.9734 * 10^-3 = 0.0009734 ? Because I am not sure

Comment: That's the so called Scientific Notation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have `y = Xe-3` that's a shorter way of saying `y = X * 10^-3`. Since multiplication distributes and the `e` operator only looks for the next number by default, yes, `1e-3 * X = X * 1e-3 = X * 10^-3`. Likewise for addition.

Answer (score 0):

Yes

```
>> 1.0e-03 * 0.9734
ans =
    0.0009734
>>
```